# Javascript - dynamically adding event handler to a form field

Tags: javascript

Would it be possible for me to dynamically add an event handler to a form field. I need to do this, because in the scope of the work I am doing - the form field to which this is added is chosen dynamically.

So, I want to know if something like this would work:

```
document.forms['Form1'].elements['chosen_field'].onkeydown = some_function();
```

EDIT:

Another sub-question here. I want to pass on the event to some_function(), but do not want to return anything back. Is there a way I can do that? Essentially I am using some_function() to update some JS variable - and for that I need to find out what key was pressed.

Comment: If you remove the `()` (unless `some_function` returns the event handler of course) and `chosen_field` is the only field with that name, then yes, this should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign event handlers like this

```
 document.forms['Form1'].elements['chosen_field'].onkeydown = some_function();
```

You are saying assign whatever `some_function` returns to this keydown event.

You need to drop the `()` from it so you assign a reference to the function.

```
 document.forms['Form1'].elements['chosen_field'].onkeydown = some_function;
```